# How to create findViewById parm dynamically or programmatically at runtime

Tags: android

I have an xml layout that will display a grid made up of textviews within tablerows.  The textview names are cell00, cell01, etc.  At runtime, my program will determine which cell needs to be changed.

Is there a way get format a name so that it can be passed to the findViewById method at runtime?  For example, if cell00 is needed, how can I generate the parm in this code?

```
TextView currcell = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cell00)
```

Something like “cell”+00 doesn’t compile because the findViewById method doesn’t accept a String type.  I don’t want have every textview name in the grid hardcoded in the program – there must be a better way.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: just curious what you are trying to accomplish by using a tableview over a grid view?

Comment: This simple first-time app will display a crossword puzzle solution.  The only way I know how to make the grid is with textviews inside tablerows.  The textview allows me to enter data in each cell and even use HTML to get certain features.  I tried to find out how professional crossword puzzle grids are made, but finally accepted defeat and gave up.   I’m sure others use a better method than mine.  I really wish I know how to make a real nice looking grid type template.

Comment: @schwiz One reason to use a table layout instead of a grid view, is if you need a particular number of items in each row.  A grid view just wraps the content at the end of each row, so the number in a row will vary based on the size of screen, etc.

Comment: Hmm, good point but for that kind of a layout I would personally prefer a RelativeLayout, but hey maybe I'm Table bias.

Answer (score 4):

You could use reflection to find the integer value of a named variable in R.id.

```
Class clazz = R.id.class;
Field f = clazz.getField("cell" + "00");
int id = f.getInt(null);  // pass in null, since field is a static field.
TextView currcell = (TextView) findViewById(id);
```

Keep in mind that reflection can be slow.  If you do it a lot, you might want to cache values or come up with a different way.

Comment: Very helpfull.  I really appreciate your time.  I have entered the code and got a clean compile.  I should have come to this site weeks ago.

Answer (score 3):

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("cell00", "id", getPackageName());
TextView currcell = (TextView) findViewById(id);
```

Like Mayra's way the code also uses reflection, so be careful.

Comment: Ty for the suggestion.  I'm trying both ways to see which works best for my needs.