# How do i call many views at one?

Tags: android, view

My problem is, i have to make a timetable. For that i made the raw table with the Views i need. For changing the subjects i made Spinners. For just looking at it i use TextViews. In total there are over 100 Views. I don't want to write ervery Id in an Array for calling them. So i want to do that programaticly. How do i call them?

I tried using `findViewByTag()` but it could't resolve it. I asumed then, that it is not working or there no explanation for it.

Also i have tried to call them in a for loop

```
for (int i =1; i <100; i++){
String ViewGetter = "R.id.View"+i;
View v = this.findViewById(ViewGetter)
}
```

logocaly it doestn't work, because `findViewById()` needs an integer. Is there a way i can call them like this?

Making a loop for getting the Id in an Array doesn't work because the Ids aren't for some reason cronological.

EDIT: as sugestet in the comment, that i could use reflections, i tried it. It hasn't worked. But it may be because i have never worked with reflections before. If this is the anwser. than i would be glad to have an explanation for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create findViewById parm dynamically or programmatically at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806847/how-to-create-findviewbyid-parm-dynamically-or-programmatically-at-runtime)

Comment: @Hamed.Ghaderian it doesn't work for me because i get nonNull exeptions and i don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getChildAt()

```
for (int i = 0; i < view.getChildCount(); i++) {
            view.getChildAt(i)...

    }
```

Comment: is there a way to exept a view? because the first colum is not to be changed

Comment: Maybe if you check if(i % rawCount == 0)